# String formatting in Tcl script

Tags: linux, tcl, expect

I am having a time format in a variable as:

TIME 12/12/12

I need to reformat it into 12-12-12.  How I can do it in a Tcl (Expect) script?

My script is test.tcl:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set time "12/12/12"

# here I need something so time will become 12-12-12
puts $time 
# I will get 12-12-12
```

Comment: Have we forgotten the lessons of Y2K already? 'Tis sad...

Comment: 12/12/12 is not a very good example. Do you mean mm/dd/yy -> yy-mm-dd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tcl has a built in string function for this:

`string map {/ -} $time`

You'll have to either put this after `puts` or in a new `set`:

`puts [string map {/ -} $time]`
or
`set time [string map {/ -} $time]`

Comment: :its not changing , giving same while printing the $time after above statement

Answer (score 3):

```
set time [clock format [clock scan $time] -format "%y-%m-%d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:
set datestring [clock format [clock seconds] -format "%y%m%d" -gmt true]
good luck